# Which grant type should I use Identityserver4 and Xamarin mobile

Tags: xamarin, identityserver4

I want to use identityserver4 user validation in my Xamarin application. But I could not decide which grant type will be used for native application.

- authorzation_code
- implicit

And the access token has expiration date. How can I get the new token? Should I use username and password in mobile application?

Comment: For native applications, the recommended flow is the authorization code with PKCE. You can read this nice article by Brock Allen, where he explains the current state for native/spa applications: https://brockallen.com/2019/01/03/the-state-of-the-implicit-flow-in-oauth2/

Answer (score 2):

**authorzation_code + PKCE** is a must flow for native apps.

In Identity Server, when configuring the client, set:

`RequirePkce = true` to enable PKCE

`RequireClientSecret = false` -- the secret not needed, PKCE replaces it

`AllowOfflineAccess = true` to enable possibility requesting [Refresh token](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html) (one time code for requesting a new token after the old one expired)

Here is [an article](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/08/using-pkce-with-identityserver-from_9.html), describing Xamarin configuration.
I see an extension [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth.Extensions/) for refresh token support in the official authentication module for Xamarin, but unfortunately it looks like MS does not move it forward anymore. [This official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth) is almost 2 years old, and [this question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129007/how-to-keep-user-logged-in-microsoft-authentication-page-using-xamarin-forms) does not have any answer yet. [This sample](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/XamarinForms) uses an alternative lib (from IdSrv suite).

Comment: What is the best way to implement registration of a new user? Should we do it within the app or on the IDP? Is it possible to auto-login the user post register?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187173/oidc-register-auto-login-flow-for-mobile-apps @d_f

Comment: Any client app is obviously less secure than a web page with a same-site session cookie provided by the server. But a new user registration is not a kind of the most sensitive operations. Anyway when you perform a registration within a web view, it's easier to end up logging in within the same context (your client can initiate the process as an ordinary login with a parameter, so getting the control back, it even doesn't feel the difference). Only my thoughts though, the final solution is yours.